# How to make VS2010 behave like VS2008 when it injects an interface implementation stub in the code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I could not find a better title for my question, but you are welcome to edit it.

Anyway, here is the question. When a C# class implements an IBlablabla interface we can run the "Implement interface IBlablabla" command in the editor and the studio would inject a stub implementation of that interface. Now, in VS2008, the implementation is surrounded by the

```
#region IBlablabla Members
#endregion
```

Whereas none of this happens in VS2010. I really liked the old behavior, does anyone know how to make VS2010 work like VS2008 in this respect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still does this, here's what I get when I ask it to implement IDisposable:

```
class Test : IDisposable {
    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is controlled by an option: Tools + Options, Text Editor, C#, Advanced, "Surround generated code with #region" check box.  If that's on, the default, then look for some kind of add-in disabling or replacing that functionality.